# Linewidth Error in Bloodpressure example of MATLAB App Designer

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to learn how to use Matlab's new App Designer feature. I downloaded the example blood pressure app, available from [MATLAB's example page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/blood-pressure-app-in-app-designer.html).

When I tried to run it, I got the following error, without any input on my part:

> Error updating Marker.
>
> LineWidth of more than 0.8 is not supported.

I am not sure where this error is coming from. The app still works, but any time I interact with any of its buttons, the error appears again.

Answer (score 0):

The default linewidth is 1, I believe. Do you have a startup file, or changed the default linewidth, since I'm surprised the defaults give an error. Are you sure its an error and not a warning? A simple solution is to explicitly set the linewidth or the [default linewidth.](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html)